# Update value of one table with summed value of related table by using intermediate table

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have three tables A, A_B and B.
Since mySQL doesn't support many to many relationships, tables A and B are related to each other by intermediate table A_B.

```
Table A:    Table A_B:  Table B:
aId aCount  aId bId     bId bCo
1   10      1   1       1   4
2   15      1   2       2   5
3   20      2   1       3   6
            3   2       4   7
            3   4
```

Now I want to add bCount of each bId to each related aCount.
Desired result:

```
Table A:    Remark:
aId aCount  (Current aCount + all related bCounts)
1   19      (10 + 4 + 5)
2   19      (15 + 4)
3   32      (20 + 5 + 7)
```

My mySQL knowledge is too basic.
I can create a SELECT query which gives me a result table like i want table A to look like after update, but I can't create the update statement. Everything I tried led to syntax errors or undesired results.
I also had one statement which might had work, but it took way to long to execute. Now I'm just confused about what to do.
Desired Result looks like:

```
SELECT `aId`, aCount + SUM(`bCount`) as `aCount` from `A`
INNER JOIN `A_B` ON `A_B`.`aId` =   `A`.`aId`
INNER JOIN `B`   ON   `B`.`bId` = `A_B`.`bId`
GROUP BY `aId`;
```

Is an update like I want even possible with a single query or do I need multiple (performance wise)?
Can anyone help me out with an approach or with creating statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0b6a287d41eed001710e94612c4228ba

```
select x.id,x.val,sum(tableb.val)+x.val as vals from 
(select * from tablea inner join tableab on tablea.id=tableab.id1) x inner join
tableb on x.id2=tableb.id 
group by x.id,x.val,id1
```

Output:

```
id  val vals
1   10  19
2   15  19
3   20  32
```

To update tablea:

```
UPDATE tablea INNER JOIN
(SELECT x.id, x.val, SUM(tableb.val) + x.val as vals FROM
    (SELECT * FROM tablea INNER JOIN tableab ON tablea.id = tableab.id1) x INNER JOIN
    tableb ON x.id2 = tableb.id 
    GROUP BY x.id, x.val, id1)Z ON tablea.id=Z.id 
SET tablea.val = Z.vals;
```

Comment: Actually I'm looking for an UPDATE statement so table a will look the same as the result of your or mine query after this statement is executed.

Comment: Thank you so much. SQL can easily break my mind already. Do not even speak about optimal statements. ;)